# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr<Void>', is a potentially non-nullable type. Try adding

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, dart-null-safety

i want to upload image to firebase stroge but i face this  error(The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.)

```
import 'dart:ffi';
    import 'dart:io';
    
    import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;
    import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' as firebase_core;
    
    class Storage {
      final firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage storage =
          firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance;
    
      Future<Void> uploadFile(//The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr<Void>', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
        String filepath,
        String filename,
      ) async {
        File file = File(filepath);
    
        try {
          await storage.ref('pizza/$filename').putFile(file);
        } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
        
      }
    }
```

Comment: Use `void` not `Void`. And remove the `'dart:ffi'` import.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure about a return statement then either you can use `void` or `dynamic` as the return type.

If you will use `void` then you are not allowed to use return, but in case if you use `dynamic` then you can either use a return statement or not.

And if it is the case with an async function then you can enclose the return type under `Future<return_type>`. For your case you might want `Future<dynamic>` or just `dynamic` will work.